# Mysql - how to do this sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a "reviews" table with N records with 3 fields.

Field ID, field name and score field.

What I am trying to do is a query that returns me a grouping by the "score" field but with values ​​between sections.

In other words, I want to group the records with a score from 0 to 1 ... records with a score from 1 to 2 ... and so on up to 5.

Now , i'm doing it with 5 different sql like this

```
    Select ifnull(avg(score),0) as avg_score,count(*) as count from reviews where score between 0 and 1 and status=1;

    Select ifnull(avg(score),0) as avg_score,count(*) as count from reviews where score between 1.01 and 2 and status=1;
```

Comment: Your table has _columns_ (not fields.)

Comment: Please add some sample data with expected output.

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`, and use `case` _expressions_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for something like below. If you need you can add other columns as well in GROUP BY.

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
CASE
    WHEN score <= 1 THEN '0-1'
    WHEN score <= 2 THEN '1-2'
    WHEN score <= 3 THEN '2-3'
    WHEN score <= 4 THEN '3-4'
    WHEN score <= 5 THEN '4-5'
    ELSE 'Other'
END 
FROM reviews
GROUP BY
CASE
    WHEN score <= 1 THEN '0-1'
    WHEN score <= 2 THEN '1-2'
    WHEN score <= 3 THEN '2-3'
    WHEN score <= 4 THEN '3-4'
    WHEN score <= 5 THEN '4-5'
    ELSE 'Other'
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `FLOOR` function as follows:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(FLOOR(SCORE), ' - ', FLOOR(SCORE) + 1) AS SCORE_RANGE, 
    IFNULL(AVG(SCORE), 0) AS AVG_SCORE,
    COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM
    REVIEWS
WHERE STATUS = 1 AND FLOOR(SCORE) <= 5 -- adjust value according to your requirement
GROUP BY FLOOR(SCORE);
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL supports the use of aliases in `GROUP BY`, which can simplify the logic:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN score <= 1 THEN '0-1'
             WHEN score <= 2 THEN '1-2'
             WHEN score <= 3 THEN '2-3'
             WHEN score <= 4 THEN '3-4'
             WHEN score <= 5 THEN '4-5'
        END) as score_group,
       AVG(score) as avg_score, COUNT(*) as num_scores
FROM reviews r
GROUP BY score_group
ORDER BY MIN(score);
```

Comment: @edica . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?